# Working with buttons in a TListView

Tags: listview, delphi, button, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I created a TListView in my Form, changed the **ItemAppearance** to **DynamicAppearance**. On the structure I went on ListView1> ItemAppearance> Item> Add New ...> and I picked the TTextButtonObjectAppearance.

Ok, now I want to know how can I set the OnClick event in this button, because when I double click the 'Code Tab' doesn't open, and the Event Tab in Object Inspector has nothing to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the AppearenceObjectName of the buttons to Delete and Edit.

```
procedure TForm2.ListView1ButtonClick(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListItem; const AObject: TListItemSimpleControl);
begin
  if AObject.name = 'Delete' then
    showmessage('Delete')
  else if AObject.Name = 'Edit' then
    showmessage('Edit');
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I put this code on the 'OnButtonClick' event of my listView. The problem happen when I click on the button (the edit button, not listView item). Looks like there's no collider on the button, the click just ignore hiim and go to the item (from the listView).

Comment: Did you change the AppearenceObjectName of the buttons?

Comment: I don't think I can make this on the Inspector. But I figure out how to make this work, just verify the name of the button and call the rigth method based on this information. Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 2):

Fill ListView

```
  with ListView1.Items.Add do
  begin
    Text := 'Item';
    Data['dateUpdate'] := '09.05.2017';
  end;
```

OnItemClickEx event

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ItemClickEx(const Sender: TObject; ItemIndex: Integer; const LocalClickPos: TPointF;
  const ItemObject: TListItemDrawable);
begin
  if ItemObject.Name.Equals('dateUpdate') then
    ShowMessage('AppearenceObjectName = "dateUpdate"');
end;
```