# How to detect click on Item.TextButton3 on ListView in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I added `TextButton2` and `TextButton3` for a `TListView` using `DynamicAppearance`.

I would like to identify the clicked button in the `TListView.OnButtonClick` event.

In my case, `TextButton2` is used for decrementing a number, and `TextButton3` is used for incrementing the number. Their purpose is similar to a SpinBox control.

Do you have any good idea?

IDE: Delphi 10.3.3 / Target: Android 32bit

[image]

Comment: Assign separate numeric values to the `Tag` property of each button. Check the `Tag` property in the `OnClick` event to know which button fired the event.

Comment: As you say TButton component have Tag property, but I can not find Tag property in TextButton2 and TextButton3 under ListView1 > ItemAppearance > Item. And they have no events in the object inspector.

Comment: I don't have `rio` and can't verify, but if the textbuttons really don't have a `tag` property, they obviously have a text anyway. Use that to differentiate the buttons.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804162/working-with-buttons-in-a-tlistview).

Comment: Tom Brunberg, Olivier, Thank you for your advice. 
AObject.name = 'TextButtonX' is working well.